# How can one put a "[" after \item?

Tags: lists, brackets, optional-arguments

The following does not compile because of the `[` after the `\item`. I presume it is because LaTeX expects a `]` as per the `\item[option`] syntax. However, I just want to insert the `[` character into the text as the first character of the enumerated item.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item before
\item [ random text
\item after
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like LaTeX to generate a document:

> before
>
> [ random text
>
> after

One way I've come up with is to put a `\`  in front of the `[`, however I'd appreciate thoughts on the least invasive way to do this.

Comment: What you've done is initializing the `displaymath` environment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just like whenever you want to put a special character (such as a space, or something else) after a command, you can use the `{}` to suppress the next character.

```
\item{}[your random text
```

Comment: Another option is to insert some other command, such as \relax (which does nothing at all) between \item and the bracket.

Comment: @JouniK.Seppänen I don't like the `{}` tweak, because it looks like that it is an argument of `\item`, which is not true. So I agree with Jouni that `\relax` is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

`\item` looks ahead for the `[` character in its definition using `\@ifnextchar [`:

```
\def\item{%
  \@inmatherr\item
  \@ifnextchar [\@item{\@noitemargtrue \@item[\@itemlabel]}}
```

This is done to enable an optional argument for `\item`. In that sense, using anything other than `[` *before* using `[` would suffice.

If you *never* use the optional argument for `\item`, you could remove it from its definition and use something different like `\Item`. That way you can use `[` without worrying about it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Remove optional argument from \item
\newcommand{\Item}{\@inmatherr\item\@noitemargtrue\@item[\@itemlabel]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \Item before
  \Item [ random text
  \Item after
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `\item` renewal removes the conditional "peeking" for a `[` in the input stream, setting the default optional argument to be the regular label. As mentioned, if you never use it in any of your lists, this should be no problem.

Comment: Beware, for this to be safe it's not enough that _you_ never use `\item[]`. You must also not use any commands or environments that use this internally. latex.ltx uses this for theorems and bibliography items for example, and probably several packages do likewise.

Comment: An alternative would be to create an `\Item` command that does not have optional arguments, and use that.

Comment: Sorry, but this is _bad_ advice when a simple `{}` is enough.